# Set initial value for enhanced for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I am going to replace this basic for loop:

```
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
 // do something with list
}
```

With this enhanced version:

```
for (long i : list) {
    // do something with list
}
```

But second loop starts with `0`, i want to start with `1`

Comment: It starts with 0 because this is the first valurle of your list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not the way the enhanced for loop works, because they are not using indexes. If you want to start at a given index, you will have to go with a standard for loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a standard `for` loop with initial index `1`:

```
for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
    // do something with list.get(i)
}
```

One situation when this may be a bad idea is if `list` is a `LinkedList`, as `get` for a `LinkedList` has time complexity `O(n)`. In this case, it would be more efficient to combine an enhanced for loop with a call to `subList`:

```
for (Long a : list.subList(1, list.size())) {
    // do something with a.
}
```

In Java 8 we can also do

```
list.subList(1, list.size()).forEach(...)
```

or

```
list.subList(1, list.size()).stream()...
```

Comment: I'd say the standard for loop is always a bad idea if you don't need the index and don't need to remove elements as you iterate, because the enhanced for loop is much more readable IMO.

Comment: @Joffrey You may be right. If you don't know the type of the `List` you should definitely prefer a for each loop. I think for an `ArrayList` I would use a standard for loop in this case.

Comment: Even if I know it's an `ArrayList`, I'd go for an enhanced for loop if I don't need the index. This is because the idea I convey with an enhanced for loop is "I iterate over the list", while the standard for loop just shows a counter that happens to be used in the `get()` method later on. I find it semantically different, even if technically it's not much, I concede.

Comment: @Joffrey I've changed the answer to say you *can* use an ordinary loop with initial index 1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about what you want to iterate on.

If you want to use the values in your list, and you don't care about the index, then go for an enhanced for loop:

```
for (Long value : list) {
    // do something with value
}
```

Here, `value` will contain each value of your list at each turn. If your list contains [5, 10, 2, 9], then `value` will be 5 at the first loop, 10 during the second etc. It has nothing to do with indexes.

If you need the index, and here it seems so (but we don't know why), then declare it explicitly with a **standard for loop**.